# PyScripter always says: "Python could not be properly initialized. We must quit."

Tags: pyscripter

I've googled for a solution, and based on that, let me report a few details:

I've tried 32-bit PyScripter-v2.6.0-Setup.exe with 32-bit python-3.6.1.exe; and 64-bit PyScripter-v2.6.0-x64-Setup.exe with 64-bit python-3.6.1-amd64-webinstall.exe.

I'm on a 64-bit Windows 10 machine.

I uninstalled other versions of Python on the machine.

Tried unzipping rpyc in the \Lib\ folder, as someone suggested that [here](https://github.com/pyscripter/pyscripter/issues/608).

What else should I be looking at?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a tested Solution

1. Remove old PyScripter
2. Install Python from Python website. I installed mine from: 
   http://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.3.2/python-3.3.2.amd64.msi (and it worked)
3. Now install PyScripter-v2.6.0-x64-Setup.exe from https://sourceforge.net/projects/pyscripter/files/

This should solve the problem.

I got this solution from https: //github.com/pyscripter/pyscripter/issues/715

Comment: Lovely.  The difference from what I'd done before was using the .msi, not the .exe for the Python.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are using an old version of Pyscripter.  Version 3.4 from https://sourceforge.net/projects/pyscripter/ provides support for all released python versions, virtual environments, conda distibutions and the ability to switch between them without exiting Pyscripter.